# Breeze query returning null value for columns that does contain data in datatabase

Tags: breeze

```
  var query = EntityQuery.from('Cases')
            .where("ID", "==", id);
```

When I try to execute the above query for an ID value, it returns null value for 2 columns and the record in the table does contain values for it. The columns are string.

```
  return datacontext.getCase(caseID, vm.caseObj).then(function () {
            alert(vm.caseObj().AuditTypeCd());
  });
```

caseID is a global variable which contains the desired ID. If I replace that with a constant value of any ID (10 or any other ID), I see that the property AuditTypeCd is fetched.

The query returns null value for few columns when global variable caseID is used. A very strange behavior.

Comment: Please clarify the question. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I am trying to fetch a record from a table for an ID value. The results of the breeze query contains null value for few columns which does contain value in database.

Comment: I have also edited my question.

Comment: Sorry but you are still not being clear enough. We can't tell what your model is like on either server or client or what is happening on the server. Here's a thought. Take Breeze out of the equation. What happens when you send the query URL to the web api. In a browser address bar you write something like `http://localhost:your-port/breeze/your-controller/cases?$filter=ID eq 10` What do you get back? It it isn't what you expect, you know to work your way back the server stack, probably by debugging into it or (better) w/ tests

Comment: I did use fiddler to see the data returned by server. All the properties are populated but somehow on client I get the values of 2 properties as null. I am now going to query the local cache to see if I get all the properties on client.